# How do I decrease page margins without being clipped to the right and the bottom?

Tags: margins

To decrease page margins, I tried increasing these values:

```
\textwidth=7in \textheight=8in
```

However, the text got wider and taller but the left and top margins did not decrease.

I then tried setting some other values to 0 too.

```
\topmargin = 0in \oddsidemargin = 0in \evensidemargin = 0in
```

However, the left and top margins still exist. How do I decrease the left and top page margins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0in,right=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Or use any other value of the size. You can as well specify `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in]{geometry}`, which does exactly the same.